# Ввод текста в сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня такой вопрос я сайт делаю для смартфонов да я тут у меня такой код

```
<div style="margin-top:15px;"></div>
 <form>
<INPUT style="height:30px; "placeholder="Ad Soyad" type="text" name="ad" value="" required><br>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Я работаю с средой в браузере там выбираю устройство экран уменьшаеться т.д. Я этот код ввел и попробовал нажать и писать что то никак не получается а как только в обычный режим переключаюсь все работает.Интересно то что когда нажать можно по концу input-a  Это не все я хочу ссылки с картинками делать нажал и куда то но вы поняли это тоже нажать не полчуается в чем проблема? А вот код страницы:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>EasyShop.az</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="html/images/icon.ico">
<meta name="robot" CONTENT="all">
<script src="//code.tidio.co/c2s9g7dvyo39mk0cp6sccgxywtg06ddi.js"></script>

      <meta name="copyright" CONTENT="Bakunights.ml © 2017. All Rights Reserved.">
        <meta name="author" content="Mahmud Shahmuradov">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="h9oFs_Mgpf6-MIMEiyDFjekbqi_kJJYvZB4CUrcHUok" />
    <meta name="language" CONTENT="az">
    <meta name="description" content="Türkiyədən  məhsulların çatdırılma xidməti" />
<meta name="keywords" content="baglama, turkiye, turkiye unvani, azerbaycan, karqo, cargo, Türkiyədən, qiymet, , mehsullarin, catdirilmasi, sifariş, sifaris" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="html/styles/stylemob.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Subrayada" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
*{transition:all 0.5s ease; font-family:arial;}
body{
        background:url(html/images/goodwp1.jpg) top left repeat-x #afafaf ;
margin:0;
}
a{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
background-color:red;
}
nav{position:fixed; top:5px; left:5px; width:250px;}
#button-menu{
padding:5px; width:35px; background:#9c9c9c; border-radius:2px;
}
#button-menu div{ width:25px; height:4px; margin:5px; background-color:white; border-radius:2px;}
#option-menu{ margin-top:15px; background:#3b84d3; position:relative; left:-350px;}
#option-menu div{padding:10px 10px 10px 25px;transition:all 0.5s ease;}
#button-menu:hover{cursor:pointer;}
#option-menu div:hover{ padding-left:50px; cursor:pointer;}
ul li{
    list-style:none;
}
ul.servic a {
    display:block;

    background:url(html/images/pinn_blue.png) center left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size:12px;


    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#423331;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }   

ul.servic a:hover { 
    color:#423331;
    text-decoration:underline;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}
var status=0;
function show_menu(){
if(status==0){
_('option-menu').style.left="0px";
status=1;
}else{
_('option-menu').style.left="-350px";
status=0;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
 <div id="button-menu" onclick='show_menu()'>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
 </div>
 <div id="option-menu">
 <div><a href="mobile.php"> Ana Səhifə</a> </div>
 <div><a> Xidmətlər</a> </div>
 <div><a href="gallerymobile.php"> Shopping </a></div> 
 <div><a > Əlaqə</a> </div> 
 <div><a href="loginmob.php"> Şəxsi Hesab</a> </div> 
 </div>
 </nav>
<center> <div style=" width:100%;margin:0px auto; background-color:white;">
    <div style=" margin-top:50px;width:100%; background:url(html/images/bg_slogan.gif) left top repeat-x;"> <h3 style="color:white;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" class="">Əlaqə</h3></div>
</div>
 </center>
 <div style="margin-top:15px;"></div>
 <form>
<INPUT style="height:30px; "placeholder="Ad Soyad" type="text" name="ad" value="" required><br>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проблема 1

В `<head></head>` Добавьте

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

2. Проблема 2

   Если честно не понял вторую проблему объясните подробнее

Comment: Это я добавил. Вторая проблема этот я хочу сделать так чтобы картинка была какая та с ссылкой нажал например и ты в Фейсбуке думаю поняли нажать невозможно с телефона а с компютера в нормальном виде можно

Comment: оберните картинку в тег `<a>`